# PHP PDO Fetch_Assoc not returning correctly

Tags: php, pdo

I have searched, and maybe I am searching for the wrong thing, but I need help with the below code. I must be missing something...

Database Class:

```
    class Database {
    private static $link = null;

    private static function dbLink() {
        if(self::$link) {
            return self::$link;
        }

        $dsn = null;

        switch(DB_DRVR) {
            case 'mysql':
                $dsn = DB_DRVR . ":host=" . DB_HOST . ";dbname=" . DB_NAME;
                break;
        }

        self::$link = new PDO($dsn, DB_USER, DB_PASS);

        return self::$link;
    }

    public static function fetchAssoc($sql) {
        $stmt = self::query($sql);
        $result = array();

        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        return $result;
    }

    public static function __callStatic($name, $arguments) {
        $callback = array(self::dbLink(), $name);
        return call_user_func_array($callback, $arguments);
    }
}
```

Portion of code returning error:

```
        $sql = "SELECT group FROM users WHERE username='ryan';";
        $dbSQL = Database::fetchAssoc($sql);

        echo $dbSQL['group'];
```

Database setup:

> - id(auto_increment, primary)
> - name(tinytext)
> - username(tinytext)
> - password(tinytext)
> - salt(tinytext)
> - email(tinytext)
> - group(tinytext)
> - privileges(tinytext)

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch() on a non-object
in C:\public_html\kernel\database.php on line 38
```

However the odd part is if I change the SQL to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='ryan';";
```

I don't get the error, it displays properly, and if I change the SQL statement to:

```
$sql = "SELECT username FROM users WHERE username='ryan';";
```

and call $dbSQL['username'] it works fine using the function above.

My Question: How come when I try to use the 'group' column in my $dbSQL array, I am receiving an error, but when I try to use the 'username' column, everything runs fine. What am I missing?

Thanks,
Ryan

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT `group` FROM users WHERE username='ryan'
```

Comment: non-member error with pdo usually means that you had error in your query. In this case - 'group' should be escaped

Comment: Oh, wow do I feel dumb. I should have seen that. Thanks so much for the fast response!

Comment: FYI: This only works in MySQL. Quotes (actually double quotes) are part of the SQL standard for quoting table names; MySQL uses backticks (as well as quotes) and SQL Server uses brackets.

Answer (score 1):

`GROUP` is a reserved keyword in SQL, your query produces an error if you use it. Quote it:

```
SELECT `group` ...
```

Answer (score 1):

It sounds to me as if your query is failing because your RDBMS reserves the word `group`.

To avoid this type of problem in future:

Implement some error checking and you would see a clue from the DB server about which part of which query fails. There are a few ways you can do this:

- Make sure your code checks [`self::errorInfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.errorinfo.php)
  after running each query, either printing or logging the output.
- Switch your errormode to `PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION`. See the manual page about [Errors and error handling](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)